# How to ensure footnotes being at the same height on every page?

Tags: listings, vertical-alignment, footnotes

I have added a footnote to the text but I also have some "unbreakable" code listings. Because of that the footnote gets dragged "higher" in the page.

[image]

[image]

As you can see there's more space between page number and the text in the second picture. How can I ensure that footnotes are always on the same height ?

Comment: Can you reproduce this behaviour in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Package `footmisc` provides option `bottom` that forces the footnotes to the bottom of the page (useful for `\raggedbottom`).

```
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding a `\vfill` as part of the `\footnoterule` redefinition will push the footnote to the bottom of the page.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\let\svfootnoterule\footnoterule
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vfill\svfootnoterule}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
This is a test\footnote{My footnote}
\lipsum[4]
\clearpage
\lipsum[1-3]
This is a test\footnote{My footnote}
\lipsum[3-4]
\end{document}
```

To clarify the approach, in response to a comment, the `\let\svfootnoterule\footnoterule` stores a copy the original definition of `\footnoterule` (which is the horizontal line above the footnote) under a new name for later use.  Then, `\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vfill\svfootnoterule}` redefines the `\footnoterule` by adding stretchable glue (`\vfill`) and then reinvoking the saved definition.

[image]

Comment: This example also works but can you explain exactly what each line (word) of those 2 lines making the rule means ?

Comment: @Patryk Done, as requested.

Comment: Thanks for that :) Although for me Heiko's answer provides easier approach.